# Trying to combine multiple programs together

Tags: java, class, methods, java.util.scanner

I am trying to take 3 different programs I have created and put them under a single class. My professor has stated I must do this and I have no clue on how to. I am not looking for a hand out here, just some how I can do this quickly and efficiently. I am also trying to figure out how to call from the same scanner for each program or if I should just make multiple ones.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AssignmentOneFahrenheit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello, I can convert Fahrenheit to Celsius!");
    System.out.println("Please enter the degrees Fahrenheit you want converted.");

    double degreesF;
    double degreesC;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    degreesF = keyboard.nextDouble(); //Allows user to input decimal number
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("The temperature in Degrees Celsius is: ");
    degreesC = 5*(degreesF - 32)/9;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", degreesC);
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class AssignmentOneHate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a line containing 'hate'.");
    String text = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("I have changed that line to read: ");
    System.out.println(text.replaceFirst("hate", "love"));
    keyboard.close();
}


import java.util.Scanner;
public class AssignmentOneVerticalDisplay {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int userInput;

    System.out.println("Please enter a 4 digit integer.");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println(userInput / 1000);
    userInput = userInput % 1000;
    System.out.println(userInput / 100);
    userInput = userInput % 100;
    System.out.println(userInput / 10);
    System.out.println(userInput % 10);

    keyboard.close();
}

}
```

I basically just copied and pasted 2 programs I created. If anybody can help guide me in the correct direction here that would be great.

Comment: Right now you have one file with two class definitions and two main() methods.  Change it so that you only have one class definition and one main() method.  Also, imports go at the top (I think, for Java) and you should only have each import line once.

Comment: What I did for posting on here was just copied one program and copied the other. I'm trying to figure out how to combine the 2 of them.

Comment: Yes and my comment gives you some general guidance on how to start.

Comment: I know my imports go at the top. These are 2 separate programs. I originally tried to create my second one within the first one and I was not able to enter the a line containing "hate" because I closed the scanner...but I have no idea how to call the scanner again so I can enter my line containing "hate"

Comment: @RyanLenig You said that you created 3 different programs. Can you also paste the third program?

Comment: Basically I am just trying to take these 3 and make 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Double.parseDouble(String string);` function together with a try-Catch to check if it was a number or a string in the input.

```
(...)
String text = keyboard.nextLine();
try {
    //We try and assume that it is a number
    Double number = Double.parseDouble(text);
    /**
     * Do stuff with the number like in the 1st program
     */
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    //The input turned out not to be a number.
    /**
     * Do stuff here with the string like the 2nd program
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not really certain what your trying to accomplish, but if it's really necessary you combine all three classes together try using Java Inner Classes

Answer (score 0):

I think that your professor is looking for a more object oriented solution. You can create a class that contains the three programs as separated methods like this

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class AssignmentScanner {

    public double convertToCelsius() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double degreesF = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.close();
        return 5*(degreesF - 32)/9;
    }

    public String replaceHate() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = keyboard.nextLine();
        String replacedText = text.replaceFirst("hate", "love");
        keyboard.close();
        return replacedText;
    }

    public int oneVerticalDisplay() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(userInput / 1000);
        userInput = userInput % 1000;
        System.out.println(userInput / 100);
        userInput = userInput % 100;
        System.out.println(userInput / 10);
        System.out.println(userInput % 10);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

You still need to create a main program that use this object like this:

```
public class AssignmentMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         AssignmentScanner assignmentScanner = new AssignmentScanner();

         System.out.println("Hello, I can convert Fahrenheit to Celsius!");
         System.out.println("Please enter the degrees Fahrenheit you want converted.");
         double degreesC = assignmentScanner.convertToCelsius();
         System.out.println("The temperature in Degrees Celsius is: ");
         System.out.printf("%.2f", degreesC);

         System.out.println("Please enter a line containing 'hate'.");
         String replacedText = assignmentScanner.replaceHate();
         System.out.println("I have changed that line to read: ");
         System.out.println(replacedText);

         System.out.println("Please enter a 4 digit integer.");
         assigmentScanner.oneVerticalDisplay();
    }
}
```

This way your main program only knows about the AssignmentScanner and its three methods. This make the main program easier to read and maintain. There is still room for improvement but i think it's OK for a first approach.